# Django catch unique_together in Form and don't save file

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have

```
class Document(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, null=True)

    hash = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)

    file = models.FileField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

    @property
    def gen_url(self):
        self.url = uuid.uuid4().hex

    @staticmethod
    def gen_digest(file):
        m = hashlib.md5()
        for chunk in read_by_chunk(file):
            m.update(chunk)
        digest = m.hexdigest()
        return digest

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('profile', 'hash'),)
```

When I try to create document with the same `profile` and `document` via admin, it returns an error through `Form`. It's a proper way I want reach in my view.

But:

```
if form.is_valid():

    print 'valid'
    try:
        form.save()
    except IntegrityError:
        print 'unique error'
        messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, u'already have')
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
else:
    return HttpResponse('not valid')
```

fails in error.

So questions:

1) How can I show `messages` rather that failing `IntegrityError`

2) How can I prevent `file` being created in storage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ModelForm by default should validate uniqueness, unless the field is excluded. From the [django 1.9 source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.9.x/django/forms/models.py#L286)

```
    # self._validate_unique will be set to True by BaseModelForm.clean().
    # It is False by default so overriding self.clean() and failing to call
    # super will stop validate_unique from being called.
```

Which in turn calls the model instance's validate_unique method. However, beware of the `exclude` gotcha - as per the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.validate_unique)

> `Model.validate_unique(exclude=None)`
>
> This method is similar to clean_fields(), but validates all uniqueness constraints on your model instead of individual field values. The optional exclude argument allows you to provide a list of field names to exclude from validation. It will raise a ValidationError if any fields fail validation.
>
> Note that if you provide an exclude argument to validate_unique(), any unique_together constraint involving one of the fields you provided will not be checked.

If all fails, you can call in your form's `clean` method explicitly `self.instance.validate_unique()`